# Repeated property and local variable name in same class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm puzzled to find VB.NET allowed me to declare a local variable in a method with the same name as a property in the class. I found out the error because the program didn't work as I expected but the compiler didn't even warn me about this possible conflict. A simple example of what I mean:

```
Public Class Form1
    Property Foo As Decimal

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Foo = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Foo As Integer 'This variable hides the property with the same name

        If Foo > 0 Then 'The local variable value will be used here and the if statement won't be evaluated to true
            'Do Something
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any recommendation on how to handle such situations via compiler warnings or best practices to avoid that? Going to VB from C#, I didn't even imagine such things could happen. This is not even a program I wrote, I had to modify code from someone else at work.

One solution would be explicitly referencing the property with the *Me* prefix:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Foo As Integer 'This variable hides the property with the same name

    If Me.Foo > 0 Then 'The property value will be used here and the if statement WILL be evaluated to true
        'Do Something
    End If
End Sub
```

You should get used to always reference properties that way to avoid such problems. Are there any better solutions?